# Reasonable settings for ZODB pool_size

Tags: python, connection-pooling, zodb

What's a reasonable default for `pool_size` in a `ZODB.DB` call in a multi-threaded web application?

Leaving the actual default value `7` gives me some connection `WARNING`s even when I'm the only one navigating through db-interacting handlers. Is it possible to set a number that's too high? What factors play into deciding what exactly to set it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pool size is only a 'guideline'; the warning is logged when you exceed that size; if you were to use *double* the number of connections an `CRITICAL` log message would be registed instead. These are there to indicate you *may* be using too many connections in your application.

The pool will try to reduce the number of retained connections to the pool size as you close connections.

You need to set it to the maximum number of threads in your application. For Tornado, which I believe uses asynchronous events instead of threading almost exclusively, that might be harder to determine; if there is a maximum number of concurrent connections configurable in Tornado, then the pool size needs to be set to *that* number.

I am not sure how the ZODB will perform when your application scales to hundreds or thousands of concurrent connections, though. I've so far only used it with at most 100 or so concurrent connections spread across several processes and even machines (using ZEO or RelStorage to serve the ZODB across those processes).

I'd say that if most of these connections only read, you should be fine; it's writing on the same object concurrently that is ZODB's weak point as far as scalability is concerned.

Comment: I don't expect this particular app to scale to more than a few dozen simultaneous connections (with maybe 2%-5% doing writes), it was just a little worrisome that I started getting warnings at **7**.

Comment: @Inaimathi: A typical Zope instance uses just a few threads to handle requests behind an asyncore network layer, so it doesn't need many concurrent connections, so the default is rather low. For certain cluster configurations we have instances tuned to just 2 threads even, scaling across processes instead to avoid the GIL and utilize multiple cores better.